Is there any method to call Microsoft System Center Service Manager (SCSM) using python?
I'm developing a Python chatbot that needs to interact with SCSM by making API calls to log tickets, create incidents, update records, and perform similar tasks.
Unfortunately, I haven't found any documentation or examples on how to call SCSM APIs from Python. Could anyone advise if this is possible or provide some guidance on how to approach making API calls to SCSM?
